# Attaching は to a direct quote

Tags: grammar, quotes

If a Japanese person wanted to say something like:

> I don't understand the phrase "I am flabbergasted"

then I think

> 「I am flabbergasted」という意味が分からない

would be okay.

I was wondering if you could just say

> 「I am flabbergasted」は/が分からない

without having to explicitly use a word like 意味. More generally, is it permissible to attach any particle other than と to a direct quote?

Comment: "「I am flabbergasted」という意味が分からない" >> "「I am flabbergasted」 **の**意味が分からない" のほうがいいと思います・・・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "sentence":

> 「"I am flabbergasted."という[意味]{いみ}が[分]{わ}からない。」

is ***not*** grammatical and for native speakers to understand it, we would have to ***guess*** as to what the speaker/writer is trying to convey.  Fortunately, the guessing part is not very hard in this case, but that sentence will still have the listener/reader guessing for a second.

For you to use the phrase 「～～という意味」 correctly, the ~~ part would need to be the ***meaning*** of a word/phrase/sentence, etc. in question, and ***not*** the word/phrase/sentence itself.  This is why the quotative 「と」 is used with 「意味」("meaning").

To say what you want to express grammatically and naturally using 「～～という」, you could say:

> 「"I am flabbergasted."という**文の**意味が分からない。」 [文]{ぶん} = sentence
>
> 「"I am flabbergasted."という**表現の**意味が分からない。」 [表現]{ひょうげん} = expression

***Informally***, however, you could simply say as @chocolate stated:

> 「"I am flabbergasted."**の**意味が分からない。」

Finally, your last sentence:

> 「"I am flabbergasted."**は/が**分からない。」

can be used in ***informal*** situations.

With 「は」, you can say something like:

> 「"Sod off!"**は**分かるけど、"I'm flabbergasted"**は**分からない。」 ← Contrastive 「は」

With 「が」, you can say:

> 「"Sod off!"**が**分からない。このページの[他]{ほか}の表現は[全部知]{ぜんぶし}ってるけど。」

TL;DR: Just remember that whenever you are directly attaching a "particle + verb phrase" to a quote, that expression would usually be ***informal***.

In ***formal*** speech, placing 「という + 文/表現/ことわざ」 right after the quote would be the usual way to talk about the quote.  (ことわざ = proverb)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a ーと after the direct quote, before a verb that takes that quote as its object. 
For your example, the correct translation is:
私は"I am flabbergasted"という言葉の意味がわからない。'I don't understand the meaning of the expression "I am flabbergasted" '.

Other instances For「言う」'say' and related verbs such as「ささやく」'whisper' 「叫ぶ」'say loudly, scream' etc. , 
彼女は「おはよう！」と言った/ささやいた/叫んだ。'She said/whispered/yelled "Ohayo!" '.
＊彼女は「おはよう！」を言った/ささやいた/叫んだ。　(* = unacceptable)

Hope this helps.
RS